# Express $2+\sqrt{3} + i$ in the form $ r(\cosθ+i\sinθ)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am struggling with $2+\sqrt{3} + i$, to be expressed in the form $r(\cosθ+i\sinθ)$.

The above should transofrm to  $(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2})(\cos(\frac{\pi}{12}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{12}))$

Comment: ![(sqrt(6)+sqrt(2))(cos(pi/12) + isin(pi/12))](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%28sqrt%286%29&plus;sqrt%282%29%29%28cos%28pi/12%29%20&plus;%20isin%28pi/12%29%29)

Comment: $\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}(\cos(\frac{\pi}{12}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{12}))$ is **not** of the form $ r(\cosθ+i\sinθ)$.

Comment: Not sure the tags are appropriate here, perhaps (complex-numbers) only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know that if $x + iy = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$ then $|x + iy| = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} = r$?

So if $2 + \sqrt 3 + i =  r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$ then $r = \sqrt{(2 + \sqrt 3)^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{4 + 4\sqrt 3 + 3 + 1} = 
\sqrt{8 + 4 \sqrt 3}= \sqrt{6 + 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{6} +2}=\sqrt {(\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{2})^2} =\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{2}$

So now we need to solve $\cos \theta = \frac{2 + \sqrt 3}{\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{2}}=$

$\frac {(2+ \sqrt 3)(\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2})}{(\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{2})(\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2})}= \frac {2\sqrt{6} + 3\sqrt{2}- 2\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{6}}4=\frac{\sqrt 6 + \sqrt 2}{4}$

And $\sin \theta = \frac 1{(\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{2})} = \frac {\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2}}4$

$\sin 2\theta = 2\sin \theta \cos \theta = $

$2* \frac {6-2}{16} = \frac 12$ so $2\theta = \frac {\pi}6| \frac {5\pi}6$

$\cos 2\theta = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta $

$= \frac {8 + 2\sqrt{12}}{16}- \frac {8 - 2\sqrt{12}}{16}=\frac {\sqrt 3}{2}$

So $2\theta = \pm \frac {\pi}6$.

So $2\theta = \frac {\pi}6$ and $\theta = \frac {\pi}{12}$.

Comment: Thank you, I struggled with expressing 4√3 as 2√2√6, 10x

Answer (score 2):

$$2+\sqrt3=\csc30^\circ+\cot30^\circ=\cdots=\cot15^\circ$$

$$2+\sqrt3+i=\cot15^\circ+i=\dfrac1{\sin15^\circ}(\cos15^\circ+i\sin15^\circ)$$

Now $\sin15^\circ=\sin(45-30)^\circ$ or $=\sin(60-45)^\circ$

Alternatively,

if equating real & imaginary parts $r\cos\theta=2+\sqrt3$

and $r\sin\theta=1$

Square & add

Now use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation), to find $\theta$